# How to sync variable between servers?

Tags: python, django

I plan to use 3 servers(there will have a haproxy to dispath to 3 servers but I don't servey it now ) to do load balancing

And I face a problem :
I create a object which has a function to query from database to get a list when the django start
(Because the list seldom changed but very frequently used so I inintial it at first).

If the data changed,it will push the message to rabbitmq, and 3 servers has rabbitmq clients to get it.
But the problem is the rabbitmq listener's process is not the same with django

How can it nortify to django process ??
Now my solution is call api(use localhost) when rabbitmq client got the changed.(so the guest can visit website and I can change the list)
But it have to bind `0.0.0.0`,I am not sure it's a good idea

What is a better way to sync between 3 servers ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premature optimisation is the root of all evil... This being said, what you want is a cache, not an async queue. Django has a good built-in cache framework, you just have to choose your backend (redis comes to mind but there are other options)

Comment: HI,I read this ````This means you can run Memcached daemons on multiple machines, and the program will treat the group of machines as a single cache```` on django cache framework. Is it means the cache only exist on one server,and the other machine need to visit that one every time to get value ???

Comment: Never used Memcached so I can't tell. I've been using Redis (both as cache backend and celery result backend) on a couple projects and never had an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want a shared data repository for all servers, and I'm guessing that you want this data repository to be in-memory, correct?
In this case, I can recommend Redis. You will deploy it on a fourth server, and you can get/set values into it from any server.

Redis also offers pub/sub capabilities, if you needs those. This means that servers can subscribed to be automatically notified when a value is modified. (http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

Comment: Yes,I want the list to  save in-memory,because I need it almost every secods(big request).  If I put it in redis,will it a huge load to redis??

Comment: Redis can handle very large throughput and very short latency. Do you have quantitative requirements? What's your expected number of reads/writes per second? What's the desired latency?

Comment: You could set up a Redis server, and then test its performance using redis-benchmark (http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)